# Using input box with element by.id Protractor Testing error

Tags: testing, textbox, automation, protractor, getelementbyid

I'm trying to use ids with my input box's within my login page but I get the following error with Protractor:

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By css selector, *[id="signin--username"])
```

Here is my log-in.js

```
var logIn = function() {
    this.navigate = function() {
        browser.get(browser.params.server);
    };
    this.usernameInputBox = element(by.id('signin--username'));
    this.passwordInputBox = element(by.id('signin--password'));
    this.dontHaveAnAccountButton = element(by.id('signin--no-account-question'));

    this.logInButton = element(by.id('signin--log-in'));
    this.Modal = element(by.css('.modal-dialog'));
    this.ModalButton = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[3]/div/div/form/div[3]/button'));
};

module.exports = new logIn();
```

Snippet from log-in.html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </span>
          <input type="text"
           id="signin--username" 
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="{{'username' | translate}}" 
           ng-model="username"
           name="username" 
           required
           autofocus data-autofill
           >
   </div>
</div>
```

Protractor Test Javascript File:

```
module.exports = function() {
describe('Login Page', function() {

    var loginPage = require('../pages/log-in.js');
    var saveScreenshot = require('../screenshot.js');

    beforeEach(function() {
        loginPage.navigate();
    })

    it('should log in (with correct credentials)', function() {
        browser.waitForAngular();
        loginPage.usernameInputBox.sendKeys('service');
        loginPage.passwordInputBox.sendKeys('s5rv1c5');
        loginPage.logInButton.click();
        browser.waitForAngular();
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(browser.params.server + '#/jobs/my_jobs');
    })

  });
};
```

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a timing issue. Improve navigate page object method to also wait for the page to load - *wait for the username field [to become present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf)*:

```
var logIn = function() {
    this.usernameInputBox = element(by.id('signin--username'));
    this.passwordInputBox = element(by.id('signin--password'));
    this.dontHaveAnAccountButton = element(by.id('signin--no-account-question'));

    // ...

    this.navigate = function() {
        browser.get(browser.params.server);

        var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(this.usernameInputBox), 5000, "Username field is still not present");
    };
};
```

Comment: And im getting this error too: Username field is not present, Wait timed out after 5010ms

Comment: @WebTech is this form inside an iframe/frame?

Comment: No I dont have it in an iframe/frame @alecxe

Comment: @WebTech then, it is something else. Are you sure `browser.params.server` contains the login url and the login form is there?

Comment: Yes I have checked that. That doesn't appear to be the issue. Timing is not the issue either. Any other suggestions? @alecxe

Comment: @WebTech strange..what if you also add `browser.waitForAngular()` after the `browser.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving the unique selector correctly. That is why this error occurs.

Use `element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('your user name');`

I assume that you gave the html of login text box.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: If i was to do it your way, i would have to edit and change around a lot of code. Is there anyway i can modify my own code as shown above? I have edited above to include my protractor testing file. Cheers!